# Por que mesmo quando margin e padding ta definido como 0px ainda há espaços entres os elementos?

Tags: html, css

```css
#header{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#00F;
}
  
#conteudo{
  widows: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:#0F0;
}

#footer{
  widows: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#C3C;
}

#Conteudo-Top{
  widows: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  height:250px;
  background-color:red;
}

 #Conteudo-Down{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  widows: 100%;
  height:250px;
  background-color:blueviolet;
 }
```

```html
<div id="site">
  <div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
  <div id="conteudo">
  <div id="Conteudo-Top"><h1>Conteudo TOP</h1></div>
  <div id="Conteudo-Down"><h1>Conteudo Down</h1></div>
  <div id="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div>
</div>
```

[image: Borda mesmo com margin 0px]

Comment: O porque - acredito que tenha algo a ver com o tamanho da fonte do documento. Utilize o seletor universal aplicando font-size:0; que os espaços vão sumir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CSS, utilizando o asterisco `*`, mais conhecido como [seletor universal](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletor_universal), você consegue aplicar o `padding` e o `margin` de forma geral no seu documento HTML. Logo, utilizando da seguinte forma:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

estará aplicando a todos os elementos, ficando sem espaços entre eles. É importante remover o `padding` e `margin` dos outros elementos para que não sejam sobrescritos, ou caso necessário um efeito diferente, aí sim poderia sobrescrever os elementos (dar mais espaço em um elemento em específico, por exemplo).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  border: 0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#00F;
}
  
#conteudo {
  widows: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:#0F0;
}

#footer {
  widows: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#C3C;
}

#Conteudo-Top{
  widows: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  height:250px;
  background-color:red;
}

 #Conteudo-Down {
  border: 0px;
  widows: 100%;
  height:250px;
  background-color:blueviolet;
 }
```

```html
<div id="site">
  <div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
  <div id="conteudo">
  <div id="Conteudo-Top"><h1>Conteudo TOP</h1></div>
  <div id="Conteudo-Down"><h1>Conteudo Down</h1></div>
  <div id="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div>
</div>
```